# react-facebook-login, Facebook is not asking for permission

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-login

I am adding facebook login to my add using react-facebook-login library. The problem is, I am getting user's facebook's data without asking any permissions. My code is

```
 <FaceBookLogin
  appId={PROD_APP_ID}
  autoLoad={false}
  fields='name,email,picture'
  callback={responseFacebook}
  disableMobileRedirect={true}
  scope='public_profile, email'
  render={(renderProps) => (
    <button
      onClick={renderProps.onClick}
      className='flex items-center justify-center w-full rounded-xl'
    >
      <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
        {isFbLoading ? (
          <div>
            loading
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className='flex items-center'>
            login with facebook
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </button>
  )}
/>
```

Is it something to do in developer.facebook.com settings. Do you have any ideas how can I get asked for the permission like in the photo below.

Example of Facebook asking for permissions

[image]

Comment: Users are not supposed to be asked for these permissions every time, over and over again - once they _have_ granted them, this part of the login process simply gets skipped. So presumably you simply must have logged in with the account you are using, before already ...? If you need to get the permission screen shown again, then remove the app from your user profile settings first.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in Facebook log in session. Sign out your Facebook account, you will see Facebook log in pop-up with asking for permissions.

Or try browsing web in Private mode.